# Running a Python script in the background

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Hey I'm running a python script that uses selenium.

When I run python3.5 quickstart.py it works a treat. When I use nohup python3.5 quickstart.py it doesn't work and nohup.out doesn't have any content and of course the python3.5 quickstart.py ends when I close my shell.

Comment: Very nice. So what's your question?

Comment: *doesn't work* just means nothing. You should say what happens exactly: error message, crash of computer, fire, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `&` after nohup command:

```
nohup python program.py &
```